Read external HTML from url including script-content
I want to read an external HTML page after JS scripts of this page are executed.
When I read the page as usual it doesn't includes content that is added by JS script of this page later.
How is this possible?
const xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest.XMLHttpRequest()
xmlHttp.open("GET", path)
        xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xmlHttp.readyState === 4) 
        if (xmlHttp.status === 200) 
            callback(JSON.parse(xmlHttp.responseText))
}
xmlHttp.send()


"When I read the page as usual it doesn't includes content that is added by JS script of this page later." - of course it doesn't. You are not doing anything more here, than making an HTTP request. HTTP requests do not execute JavaScript - the browser does.

@CBroe is there any workaround?

You could create an iframe -> load the url in it -> read the iframe's contents -> then delete it. This could be your JS code:
var url = "https://example.com/page.html";
var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");

iframe.style.display = "none";
iframe.src = url;

document.body.appendChild(iframe);

iframe.onload = function() {
    var iframeDocument = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;
    var iframeContent = iframeDocument.documentElement.outerHTML;

    document.body.removeChild(iframe);
    
    console.log(iframeContent);
};

For example if this would be the content of page.html:
<html>
<head>
<script>
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    document.querySelector("body").textContent = 'test';
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>

then the console.log would write out this result:
<html><head>
<script>
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    document.querySelector("body").textContent = 'test';
});
</script>
</head>
<body>test</body></html>


You cannot grab the content of an iFrame you loaded with external content

Dang it, you are correct. In this case the best idea I have, which is quite painful, but it could work: with PHP using file_get_contents or curl, copy the html file to the own server, and then use this iframe method on the owned html file.

This IS the way. A proxy.
